# Calculate accuracy of a dataset

Tags: mysql, pandas, count, statistics, left-join

I have two tables (X and Y) that maps, say, a soccer player to a team. The data in table X is reliable but I am not sure about the reliability  of the data in table Y. Table X has 3,000 rows and table Y has a 1,000. How can I calculate how accurate the mapping in table Y is by using the data in table Y as the truth set or superset?

Table X

```
PlayerID   | Name      | Team
007        | Sancho    | Dortmund
010        | Messi     | Barcelona
011        | Werner    | Chelsea
001        | De Gea    | Man Utd
009        | Lewan..ki | Bayern Mun
006        | Pogba     | Man Utd
017        | De Bruyne | Man City
029        | Harvertz  | Chelsea
005        | Upamecano | Leipzig
```

Table Y

```
PlayerID.   |Name      | Team
010         | Messi    | Man City
007         | Sancho   | Man Utd
006         | Pogba    | Man Utd
017         | De Bruyne| Man City
011         | Werner   | Liverpool
006         | Pogba    | Real Madrid
```

Based on Table X, we can see that only playerIDs 006 and 017 are accurate. However playerID 006 is partially accurate as it maps to two different teams.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. We have no idea what your datastructures look like. And if you want a SQL solution, then please tag the database you are running: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Comment: I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `left join` and use conditional logic to compute the accuracy.

In MySQL, you could phrase this as:

```
select avg(y.playerID is not null) as accuracy_ratio
from x
left join y 
    on  y.playerID = x.playerID
    and y.name     = x.name
    and y.team     = x.team
```

This gives you a value between `0` and `1`, that represents the accuracy ratio (you can multiply it by 100 if you want a percentage).

Note that this somehow assumes that `playerID` uniquely identify records in both tables.